# SQL Server error "Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with int "

Tags: sql-server

I have made below stored procedure for taking the backup of a database

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_databasebackup]  
    @DatabaseName NVARCHAR(200),
    @Path NVARCHAR(500)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @sqlQuery  VARCHAR(5000)  

    BEGIN
        SET @sqlQuery = ' BACKUP DATABASE ['+@DatabaseName+'] TO DISK = N''D:\@DatabaseName.bak'' 
                          WITH COPY_ONLY, NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N''@DatabaseName-Full Database Backup'', 
                          SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS =''10'' '

        EXEC (@sqlQuery)
    END
END
GO
```

When I execute the stored procedure with a database name and path as parameters, I get this error:

> Operand type clash: varchar is incompatible with int

Comment: **WARNING** This is *wide* open to injection attacks! `'...[' + @SomeString + ']...'` is *not* injection safe! Whenever you inject dynamic objects *always* properly quote them with `QUOTENAME`. `N''D:\@DatabaseName.bak''` is also not going to work; SQL isn't a script language, so it won't replace the value of `@DatabaseName` (which is undefined) with the value of `@DatabaseName`. Have a look [here](https://wp.larnu.uk/an-in-depth-look-at-injecting/) at how to inject values into a dynamic statement.

Comment: Just a guess, but doesn't `STATS = ` expect an integer instead of a string? What happens when you manually "fill in the blanks" in your backup statement and try to execute it?

Comment: You are backup up to disk location "D:\@databasename.bak". `Stats` should not be quoted. You don't even use `@path`. You don't even need DSQL for this, `backup database` allows you to pass parameters for database and path.

Comment: Side Note: `@DatabaseName` should be defined as a `sysname`, a synonym for `nvarchar(128) NOT NULL`, which is the data type SQL Server uses for all object names.

Answer (score 0):

You can backup a database without using Dynamic SQL.

You just need to use the backup command like this

```
backup database @DatabaseName
to disk=@DiskName
with name=@Name,
compression, format, init, skip, norewind, nounload, stats=10
```

`@DatabaseName` should be `sysname`

You need to prepare / concatenate names and paths prior to using variables in the backup command - ie, `@DiskName` would be a concatenation of a `path` and `filename` with a ".bak" suffix.

Comment: now i am getting "Backups on raw devices are not supported. 'C:' is a raw device "

Comment: In your question you have `with noformat` check this and change to `with format`